# Hide votes for answers on questions with bounties?

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounties

Often I will get an answer to a question that is, not quite right or too narrow, so as a good SE citizen I will offer a bounty on it using some of my [hard earned rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/89035/rjstelling).

However, as the first answer already has several votes, it discourages other users from even attempting to answer the question. Seven days will pass and I will be forced to give the bounty to the very answers I feel is not good enough! It's crazy!

So I suggest, *hiding the votes of answers during the length of the bounty*.

### Caveats:

- User can see votes on his/her answer
- Bounty holder can see all votes
- Mods can see all votes

Comment: Do you mean an answer before or after the bounty? If it's before, why not edit into the question: "Thanks for the answers so far. I've added the bounty because I'm really interested in XYZ." If it's after, leave a similar comment on the answer: "Thanks, but ..." In fact you can edit the question to clarify either way.

Comment: stretching the concept you may also interpret the +15 for acceptance as a "litte bounty", so we may decide to hide votes on all questions until the "bounty" is awarded. Doesn't sound good

Comment: **EDIT:** I've changed the title be be a little more clear.

Comment: @Rup yes, adding a comment is great, and I do do that but if the answer has 6, 4 or even any votes, its still off putting for people to write an answer, especially if they is a short amount of time left for the bounty to run.

Comment: I must admit it makes some sense...

Comment: *as the first answer has already got several votes it discourages other users form even attempting to answer the question* — why? It's *you* who should award the bounty. Even more, [auto-awarded bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) only apply to *new* answers, with a minimum score of as little as 2, so it would just encourage users to work for their bounty and write a better answer.

Comment: @Arjan (my point is) I can't award a bounty if there are no answers.

Comment: I agree, but ordering answers by votes is also useful. This way users can see which answers were close to an acceptable answer, but not 100% there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is necessary. Whenever I see a bounty posted on a question it's pretty clear to me that the bounty giver is currently not satisfied with existing answers there, otherwise there's no reason to offer the bounty in the first place.

Granted you have offered more bounties that I have, I'm just saying, I don't think it will do any good, and will only complicate things.

Comment: A user coming in on day 6 will have no idea if the answer with 3 votes is new (answered within the bounty) or old (submitted before the bounty).

Comment: @rjs well technically it can be checked, but anyway, my point is that if I see an active bounty which was not awarded, I assume that no answer is good enough for the giver. Yes, it's possible that the bounty giver is just waiting to see if anything better pops, but that's just my assumption.