# Could viewing the answer votes on questions with bounties be a privilege?

Tags: feature-request, privileges

As a follow-up to [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85874/152009), could the ability to "view votes for answers on questions with bounties" be a 1,250 or 1500 rep privilege?

In other words, we can be reasonably certain that members with a history of contributing to our community will be well behaved -- so allow them to see the votes on answers to bountied questions.

Comment: So this is assuming that the first suggestion is implemented?

Comment: Yes, if it were implemented.  I realize that no formal response has been made yet.